# Does the following principles capture the modern standard line of set theory?

Tags: set-theory, axioms, philosophy

I think that the following axioms describes what modern set theory is all about (on top of mono-sorted first order logic with equality and membership)

**Extensionality:** Two sets with the same elements are equal: $$\forall X \, \forall Y \, \big{(}\forall z \, (z \in X \Leftrightarrow z \in Y) \implies X=Y \big )$$

**Replacement:** if $f$ is a function definable in the langauge of set theory without symbol $``B"$, then: $$\forall \vec{P} \ \big{(}\forall A\, \exists B: B=\{f(x)| x \in A\}\big )$$

**Hierarchy:** Every set belongs to a limit stage of the cumulative hierarchy.

$$\forall X \, \exists \alpha \, (\lim(\alpha) \land  X \in V_\alpha)$$

**Order:** Every set is injective to some ordinal. $$\forall x \exists \, ord \, \alpha:  \exists f \, (f: x \hookrightarrow \alpha)$$

**Height:** Since stages of the cumulative hierarchy are indexed by ordinals, then this can take the form of existence axiom for ordinals. So the general form is: $$\exists \alpha \, (ord(\alpha) \land \phi)$$ which is usually a large cardinal axiom.

I think this general form captures the standard modern approach to set theories.

I know that there are non-well founded set theories, or even choice-less large cardinal axioms, but it doesn't appear that these fit the standard line, those are usually contemplated in parallel to the standard line.

> Is the above a correct capture of what's going on with modern set theories or it is an incorrect characterization? If the latter, then in what sense it is so?

Comment: I think the $\implies$ in your version of Extensionality should be $\iff $. Otherwise I don't think you can disprove $\forall x \forall y\,(x=y).$

Comment: I recommend Set Theory: An Introduction To Independence Proofs by K. Kunen, or the less demanding Set Theory by Suppes.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, the other direction is proved from equality (identity) theory. By the way, this theory of course disproves $\forall x \forall y (x=y)$ since $\emptyset$ is not a limit ordinal. Thanks for the references, I've already read Suppes.

Comment: and some of Kunen too.

Comment: "Identity theory"? Consider the sentences to be strings of symbols, with strings obtained (deduced) from others by various rules. A disproof of $\forall x,y (x=y)$ using only these rules is then needed.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, Identity theory proves that $\forall x \, \forall y ( x=y \implies \forall z ( z \in x \Leftrightarrow z \in y ))$ and since with the axiom of Extensionality that I've wrote you have the other direction, then its easy to prove the bijectional form of Extensionality you spoke about.  So there is no need to change $\implies$ to $\iff$ in Extensionality since the latter is a throem of this theory. As about $\forall x \forall y (x=y)$, this cannot be because of the axiom of Hierarchy which proves the existence of a limit ordinal, and $\emptyset$ is NOT a limit ordinal.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, of course I'm considering what you wrote about sentences being special kinds of strings of symboles and deduction, etc...; by identity theory I mean first order equality theory, that system is present here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, Suppose $\forall x \forall y (y=x)$, then take the formula $\varphi$ to be $z \in x$, now by the axiom of substitutition for formulas we have: $\forall x \forall y (y=x \to \forall z ( z \in x \iff z \in y))$. Now from Hierarchy there is a limit ordinal, fix one $\gamma$, now it follows that $\emptyset \in \gamma$, now let $x=\emptyset, y= \gamma,  z=\emptyset$ so we do  have $\neg (\emptyset \in \emptyset \iff \emptyset \in \gamma)$, so $\emptyset \neq \gamma$.